# Google Scholar: Where/How to send Emails to make corrections to them?

Tags: publications, citations, online-publication, google-scholar, reference-managers

It looks to me that various articles of mine have huge parts of missing citations from various published papers from other people. For example, by checking adsabs.harvard.edu, I find many more citations to my papers, but they are not included properly thus missing in Google Scholar.

> Where/How do I send emails to Google Scholar to reach out for this issue?

Comment: They miss a lot of citations for everyone. I don't get the impression that Google Scholar cares to become some absolute metric.